# Did I tackle this implicit differentiation problem correctly?

Tags: calculus

$$2x^3 + x^2y-xy^3 = 2$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} [2x^3+x^2y -xy^3 ] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(2)$$

$$6x^2 + \left(2xy + x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right) - \left(  1 y^3 + 3y6^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right ) = 0$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} (x^2 +3y^2)(6x^2+2x-y^3) = 0$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}  = \frac{6x^2+2x-y^3}{x^2+3y^2} $$

Did I tackle this question correctly?

Comment: I believe your $3y6^2$ should read $3xy^2$, so you are missing an $x$ in the next line (as well as some other things).

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: out of curiosity, why do you and others always remove the italicization of the differential?

Comment: @aengle Well, I don't use either style (italics or text) consistently. I think the idea of using text style is that $\mathrm d$ is not really a variable, but more like an operator of sorts. This is in contrast to the variable $x$ sitting right next to it.

Comment: @SrivatsanNarayanan Here's an answer to how differentials should technically be represented: <http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14821>

Comment: @aengle: there's a mention of this custom in *[The Not So Short
Introduction to $\LaTeX$ $2\varepsilon$](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)*. (See page 69.) The recommendation goes all the way back to Knuth (but I can't seem to find where he talked about this).

Comment: @Sri, my last comment was for you, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2x^3 + x^2y-xy^3 = 2$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} [2x^3+x^2y -xy^3 ] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(2)$$

$$6x^2 + \left(2xy + x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right) - \left(  1 y^3 + 3y^2x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right ) = 0$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} (x^2 - 3y^2x) + (6x^2+2xy-y^3) = 0$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}  = \frac{6x^2+2xy-y^3}{3y^2x -x^2} $$

Comment: OH  i got it its - on the bottom oh man -____- close enough haha

Comment: MY REP IS 1337. Nobody vote on anything of mine ever again!

Comment: LOL I WAS ABOUT TOO THO!

Comment: Wait wait how did you get the 3y^2x-x2 where did that x come from?

Comment: I was just kidding about the rep... the dy/dx is being multiplied by -1*(that), so if you add the dy/dx term to the other side it becomes positive. Then divide.

Comment: That's what I was referring to in my comment.  Product rule on $xy^3$ gives $1y^3+3y^2x\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I totally missed that but thanks! At least i was on the right track :D